# Cannot add logo in ActionBar, Android API < 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried many ways but I can't add logo in ActionBar.

I'm building application with `minSdkVersion = 9` and `targetSdkVersion = 21`, I successfully changed the **color** of ActionBar and it works with API < 11 but can't add logo yet!

I have googled a lot and also read many answers on **stackoverflow** but nothing works.

I need a logo here

[image]

I tired adding logo in `manifest` file like,

```
<application android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

and

```
<activity android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

but it doesn't work!

I also created `res/values/themes.xml` file

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>   //this is for support v7
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand. This question was answered in a previous questions by nadavfima on 8-19-14. As was stated there:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

After adding this code you will have an actionbar icon.  Please CHECK this question as answered